# Flutter ios build fails

Tags: flutter, codemagic, flutter-ios

I was successfully able to build my app for android in codemagic, but ios is just killing me. I got all sorts of errors I've seen for the first time. Many of them I hope I resolved successfully, but I haven't find the answer for this one:

```
/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

    The path  does not exist
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

So I did some googling, and if I understand correctly DerivedData hold the builds for the project. I had a look into the folder and I didn't find the Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv which explains the error.
However when I tried to build the app in xcode I had the same error except the Runner-***** directory was different and this time it was present with every other directory down to assetcatalog_generated_info.plist which then didn't make sense to me since it was present.

I tried flutter clean and wanted to build it again, but the same error would come up.

Comment: Is it your first time building with Xcode? Are you signed-in with a developer account in Xcode?

Comment: All i can suggest is hitting up the https://blog.codemagic.io/tags/slack/ slack group.

Comment: Yeah it's my first time building with Xcode. I subscribed to paid developer account.

Comment: Thanks @Emile. Didn't think of that. Will head right there.

Comment: Hi @LukasLukeStateczny did you check this thread? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23465

Comment: Hi @MikhailTokarev. Thank you so much, this article helped a big time.

Answer (score 1):

The link github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23465 from @MikhailTokarev helped big time.

By the end of the thread scut204 commented:

```
Select "Run script only when installing" in Xcode Build Phase script.
Encountered and solved.
Tutorial update demanding.
```

That solved it.